# Cannot FindControl even though it exists Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

(Dynamic Controls) On Page Pre_Init I can get the name of the control using the following code but it cannot find the control in the Panel even though it exists. So why would that be? What I need to do is get the value of the postback control before it is disposed of.

Note: this is only a Sample.

Here is the HTML

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.vb" Inherits="DynamicControls_GetControlUnloaded.WebForm2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0    Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div style="width: 200px;">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Code Behind

```vb
Public Class WebForm2
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Dim current_val As Object

Private Sub WebForm2_PreInit(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreInit
    Dim postback_control As Control = GetPostBackControl(Me.Page)

    If postback_control IsNot Nothing Then
        Select Case postback_control.GetType
            Case GetType(DropDownList)
                current_val = CType(postback_control, DropDownList).Text
            Case GetType(TextBox)
                current_val = CType(postback_control, TextBox).Text
            Case GetType(CheckBox)
                current_val = CType(postback_control, CheckBox).Checked
            Case GetType(RadioButton)
                current_val = CType(postback_control, RadioButton).Checked
        End Select
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'Create Dynamic controls
    Call BuildControls()
End Sub

Private Sub BuildControls()
    For i As Integer = 0 To 2
        Dim ddl As New DropDownList
        ddl.Items.Add("Item 1")
        ddl.Items.Add("Item 2")
        ddl.Items.Add("Item 3")
        ddl.Style.Add("margin", "3px")
        ddl.ID = "Ctrl" & i.ToString
        ddl.AutoPostBack = True
        ddl.Width = 150
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ddl)
    Next
End Sub

Public Shared Function GetPostBackControl(ByVal thePage As Page) As Control
    Dim myControl As Control = Nothing
    Dim ctrlName As String = thePage.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET")
    If ((ctrlName IsNot Nothing) And (ctrlName <> String.Empty)) Then
        myControl = thePage.FindControl(ctrlName)
    Else
        For Each Item As String In thePage.Request.Form
            Dim c As Control = thePage.FindControl(Item)
            If (TypeOf (c) Is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button) Then
                myControl = c
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Return myControl
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in this way instead of the normal way?

Comment: @ivowiblo This project is all dynamic. I am trying to get the value of the control (dropdownlist) before it is recreated.

Comment: Oh, I see you changed the whole example, let me check now :)

Comment: Yup. If you take a look at the "thePage.FindControl" in GetPostBackControl it doesn't get the control even though the name is passed to it. I changed thePage to PlaceHolder1 but that did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

You could be to early in the processing step with Pre_Init. Does your code really must be run there? See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#lifecycle_events) in the MSDN about Life-Cycle Events.

Comment: Its a dynamic control and I need to get the text from it before it is disposed.

Comment: I even put it in the Page_Load event, it gets the control name but will not find it in the Panel.

Comment: Have you tried putting it in PreRender?  This executes after Page_Load

Comment: @nycdan Thanks, but it fired off after the Load. I needed it before the Load.

Answer (score 0):

Init event is your best bet. Pre-Init is used for master pages I guess. The view state is loaded before the Init event.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create the controls in Init and not in Load, and create all of them. This will make all the events of those objects to be fired (because you are creating them before analyzing the ViewState). Then the value you want will be available from the control itself. If you need to show something different depending on the value, create all the objects and then hide the one you don't want to show (.Visible = false). They will be on ASP.NET radar besides they won't be rendered.

Answer (score -1):

`FlowLayoutPanel2` isn't available on the Page Pre_init because it's only available on the client side.  Why don't you use an `<asp:Dropdownlist>`

If you have to use a select option you can access the `<select` by adding a `runat="server"` and/or add it to the `<div id="FlowLayoutPanel2"` to access both of them from the server side.

```
    <div id="FlowLayoutPanel2" style="width:300px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;" runat="server">
        <span>Select type of item:</span>
        <select name="ctrl1" runat="server" ...>
            <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
            <option value="Item 1">Item 1</option>
            <option value="Item 2">Item 2</option>
            <option value="Item 3">Item 3</option>
            <option value="Item 4">Item 4</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: I am using the dropdownlist. The html i posted was the source code durring debugging in the browser.

Comment: I was trying to get the value of the dynamic control before it gets re-created in the load event. Can't quite figure out how to do that.

Comment: can you post your HTML in the source file?

Comment: I edited the original post with html and code. I used a PlaceHolder instead of Panel instead, but thats irrelevant for the root of quesion. thanks for your time.

Comment: You should be able to get the values in the Load section before calling the BuildControls function, why do you need to do it in the pre-init, seems like overkill. Also Check out this answer, it might help you as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4706866/55455 basically states you can't read the values in the pre_init.

Comment: I moved the code in Pre_Init to Load before the BuildControls but doesn't work. I can get the value if i add handler to each control, but that fires off after the Load. That is to late because I need the value of postback control as BuildControls is dependend upon that value.

Comment: the handler should fire before the Load routine? and in the handler you could call the BindControls again after you get the results.

Comment: I just tried that but I get a "Microsoft JScript runtime error: " about multiple controls of same ID.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6237/discussion-between-robert-and-tszoro)